# perl snmp get_bulk_request function returning data for all indexes while added index in oid , snmpwalk on terminal giving correct index data not all

Tags: perl, snmp, modem

```
    $UsRx = '1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737288';
    my %table; # Hash to store the results



    my $res = $session->get_bulk_request(
        -varbindlist    => [ $UsRx ],
        -callback       => [ \&get_callback, \%table ],
        -maxrepetitions => 80,
    );

    snmp_dispatcher();

    if (!defined $res) {
        printf "ERROR: %s\n", $session->error();
        $session->close();
        exit 1;
    } 

    for my $oid (oid_lex_sort(keys %table)) {
        printf "%s,%s,\n",
        $index,
        $table{$oid};                
    }
```

**Note :** callback function not here but assume that is working correct issue seems with get_bulk_request when need a single index data then it is ignoring the given index and returning data of index, any alternative solution is also will be appreciated

```
o/p :
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737288.1337,-70
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737288.1338,-75
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737288.1339,-55
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737288.1340,-60
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737289.1337,-75
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737289.1338,-75
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737289.1339,-60
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737289.1340,-65
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737290.1337,-80
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737290.1338,-70
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737290.1339,-65
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737290.1340,-65
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737291.1337,-65
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737291.1338,-55
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737291.1339,-50
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737291.1340,-45
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737293.1337,-15


Expected o/p :
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737288.1337,-70
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737288.1338,-75
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737288.1339,-55
1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737288.1340,-60

While this working fine with snmpwalk on terminal
system@new:~$ snmpwalk -v2c -c #543%we 23.9.4.67 1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737288

iso.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737288.1337 = INTEGER: -70
iso.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737288.1338 = INTEGER: -75
iso.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737288.1339 = INTEGER: -55
iso.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.4.1.3.737288.1340 = INTEGER: -60
```

Comment: In order to have any chance of helping here, we need to know what kind of object `$session` is.

Comment: my ($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(
            -version     => 'snmpv2c',
            -nonblocking => 1,
            -hostname    => $in_hostname,
            -community   => $in_community,
            -port        => 161,
            -timeout     => 3,
            -retries     => 1
        );
@DaveCross if you are familiar with perl snmp request

Comment: Please don't dump code into comments. Comments on Stack Overflow don't support code formatting. Instead, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45211610/edit) to add the code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I am interpreting your question correctly, but it sounds like you are asking why snmpwalk (CLI tool) returns only OIDs that have the same prefix as the one you specified, while using get-bulk from your perl code returns OIDs beyond the subtree you requested.

This would be expected behavior. "snmpwalk" is not an SNMP request type; get-bulk and get-next are. Instead, "snmpwalk" is a specialized tool that uses get-next or get-bulk and handles, itself, detecting that the get-bulk or get-next has retrieved an OID outside the subtree you specified and terminating the walk. Unless the API you're using provides a similar function, you would have to implement this logic in your code. The agent is just doing what was requested: return up to 80 (per your code) varbinds **lexicographically greater than** the request OID. SNMP doesn't have a built-in request type that retrieves only a subtree.